# MongoDB to BigQuery

Tags: mongodb, google-bigquery

What is the best way to export data from MongoDB hosted in mlab to google bigquery?

Initially, I am trying to do one time load from MongoDB to BigQuery and later on I am thinking of using Pub/Sub for real time data flow to bigquery.

I need help with first one time load from mongodb to bigquery.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In my opinion, the best practice is building your own extractor. That can be done with the language of your choice and you can extract to CSV or JSON.

But if you looking to a fast way and if your data is not huge and can fit within one server, then I recommend using `mongoexport`. Let's assume you have a simple document structure such as below:

```
{
    "_id" : "tdfMXH0En5of2rZXSQ2wpzVhZ",
    "statuses" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "dc9e5511-466c-4146-888a-574918cc2534",
            "score" : 53.24388894
        }
    ],
    "stored_at" : ISODate("2017-04-12T07:04:23.545Z")
}
```

Then you need to define your BigQuery Schema (`mongodb_schema.json`) such as:

```
$ cat > mongodb_schema.json <<EOF
[
    { "name":"_id", "type": "STRING" },
    { "name":"stored_at", "type": "record", "fields": [
        { "name":"date", "type": "STRING" }
    ]},
    { "name":"statuses", "type": "record", "mode": "repeated", "fields": [
        { "name":"status", "type": "STRING" },
        { "name":"score", "type": "FLOAT" }
    ]}
]
EOF
```

Now, the fun part starts :-) Extracting data as JSON from your MongoDB. Let's assume you have a cluster with replica set name `statuses`, your db is `sample`, and your collection is `status`.

```
mongoexport \
    --host statuses/db-01:27017,db-02:27017,db-03:27017 \
    -vv \
    --db "sample" \
    --collection "status" \
    --type "json" \
    --limit 100000 \
    --out ~/sample.json
```

As you can see above, I limit the output to 100k records because I recommend you run sample and load to BigQuery before doing it for all your data. After running above command you should have your sample data in `sample.json` BUT there is a field `$date` which will cause you an error loading to BigQuery. To fix that we can use `sed` to replace them to simple field name:

```
# Fix Date field to make it compatible with BQ
sed -i 's/"\$date"/"date"/g' sample.json
```

Now you can compress, upload to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) and then load to BigQuery using following commands:

```
# Compress for faster load
gzip sample.json

# Move to GCloud
gsutil mv ./sample.json.gz gs://your-bucket/sample/sample.json.gz

# Load to BQ
bq load \
    --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
    --max_bad_records=999999 \
    --ignore_unknown_values=true \
    --encoding=UTF-8 \
    --replace \
    "YOUR_DATASET.mongodb_sample" \
    "gs://your-bucket/sample/*.json.gz" \
    "mongodb_schema.json"
```

If everything was okay, then go back and remove `--limit 100000` from `mongoexport` command and re-run above commands again to load everything instead of 100k sample.

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:**

If you want more flexibility and performance is not your concern, then you can use `mongo` CLI tool as well. This way you can write your extract logic in a JavaScript and execute it against your data and then send output to BigQuery. Here is what I did for the same process but used JavaScript to output in CSV so I can load it much easier to BigQuery:

```
# Export Logic in JavaScript
cat > export-csv.js <<EOF
var size = 100000;
var maxCount = 1;
for (x = 0; x < maxCount; x = x + 1) {
    var recToSkip = x * size;
    db.entities.find().skip(recToSkip).limit(size).forEach(function(record) {
        var row = record._id + "," + record.stored_at.toISOString();;
        record.statuses.forEach(function (l) {
            print(row + "," + l.status + "," + l.score)
        });
    });
}
EOF

# Execute on Mongo CLI
_MONGO_HOSTS="db-01:27017,db-02:27017,db-03:27017/sample?replicaSet=statuses"
mongo --quiet \
    "${_MONGO_HOSTS}" \
    export-csv.js \
    | split -l 500000 --filter='gzip > $FILE.csv.gz' - sample_

# Load all Splitted Files to Google Cloud Storage
gsutil -m mv ./sample_* gs://your-bucket/sample/

# Load files to BigQuery
bq load \
    --source_format=CSV \
    --max_bad_records=999999 \
    --ignore_unknown_values=true \
    --encoding=UTF-8 \
    --replace \
    "YOUR_DATASET.mongodb_sample" \
    "gs://your-bucket/sample/sample_*.csv.gz" \
    "ID,StoredDate:DATETIME,Status,Score:FLOAT"
```

*TIP:* In above script I did small trick by piping output to able to split the output in multiple files with `sample_` prefix. Also during split it will GZip the output so you can load it easier to GCS.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is awesome. But there is a problem in this approach. Here schema of BigQuery has been fixed explicitly. But logically, the schema of MongoDB will never be fixed. So we can't rely on fixed schema file for bigquery. Secondly, there is high chance of new columns or nested columns to be there in mongoDB in newer/recent data. Then one way is to change the schema of bigquery schema file repeatedly every time a brand new key is stored in MongoDB, but then how will you handle the already uploaded data in bigquery.  Would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: I totally understand your points and that's the main reason I started my answer by suggesting you build a custom extractor. BigQuery can support nested fields, so it is not an issue. For designing a flexible schema in BigQuery, I suggest building schema with two parts. Common fields which will be fixed and mostly not change and one "meta" field with the type of ARRAY<STRUCT<k STRING, v STRING>>. This way you can push any custom value in the form of Key/Value pairs and store them all in array form within "meta" field. I used this technique a lot and it could be a good alternative option for you

Answer (score 2):

From a basic reading of MongoDB's documentation, it sounds like you can use [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) to dump your database as JSON. Once you've done that, refer to the [BigQuery loading data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data) topic for a description of how to create a table from JSON files after copying them to GCS.

Comment: How about Date fields? When I export data to date/time field show up like "$date" which is not acceptable for BigQuery field names. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I think you'll need to rename them somehow first, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you Elliott, I find a way to fix it and also submit it as another answer to this question which might help someone like me in future :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can read data from MongoDB and [stream it to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery). You can find an example in NodeJS [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/insertRowsAsStream.js).

This is an extension of the linked example that prevents duplicated records (as long as they are still streaming buffer):

```
    const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
    const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();

    ...

    const jsonData = // Array of documents from MongoDB

    const inputRows = jsonData.map(row => ({
      insertId: row._id,
      json: row
    }));
    const insertOptions = {
      raw: true
    };

    await bigqueryClient
      .dataset(datasetId)
      .table(tableId)
      .insert(inputRows, insertOptions);
```

Comment: Where would this code be running? On the mongodb server?

Comment: You would have to run it on some server or computer of your own.